# How to connnect wsl docker to intellij?

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Im running docker on wsl(Ubuntu20.04.4) in Windows10
I start docker with`sudo dockerd`
[image]

Everything started succefull.
But I dont know what values I should set in this dialog:
[image]

My Idea was to set the virtual machine path to /var/run/docker.sock but i still have no idea what im suppoed to set on local path.

The Jetbrains ducomentation is not really helpful.
What paths am I suppoed to set here?

Comment: wsl or wsl2 ? as if you are using wsl it is `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`  and if you are using wsl2  it is `tcp://localhost:2375` but surely after making sure you have exposed the docker daemon, under Settings >> General >> enable Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS option

Comment: Try to re-install docker on WSL as per https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository , run via `sudo dockerd` and update the IDE to the latest version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download . Works fine for me with default `Virtual machine path` settings in the latest IDE build